# imagemagick - generated PDFs are blurry/hazy

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have an image of a website which I'm trying to convert to PDF. I have the image in several formats: PSD, PNG, JPG, TIFF, all saved losslessly.

I'm using the following command to convert the image to PDF:

```
convert -density 93 foo.jpg bar.pdf
```

Here is part of the original image:

[image: Original]

And here is the same part, after converting to PDF:

[image: Converted]

As you can see, the second one is *ever so slightly* hazy. What's causing this, and how can I eliminate it? I've seen PDFs with crisp graphics, so I *know* it's possible.

Comment: Please post the original file, not a processed small version. Your command implies the input is JPG, which is lossy and may be the source of the slight blur. The file you posted is a PNG not a JPG. Your command is actually not proper IM syntax for a raster input image. You should read the input before setting the output density. However, IM 6 is rather forgiving and likely this won't matter. Saving to a PDF puts the raster image into a vector shell, which may lose more quality when viewing. To check, we would need to start with your original. Have you tried the same with a PNG input?

Comment: I've tried with jpg, png, and tiff

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the same results with multiple input types. The fuzziness is likely being caused by the anti-aliasing feature of your PDF Viewer. If using Acrobat, you can turn off image anti-aliasing by doing the following:

Go to Edit-->Preferences-->Page Display

Untick the option "Smooth Images" and hit "OK".

The crisp graphics you are seeing on other PDFs are likely due to the fact that they are vectorized graphics. Imagemagick is creating a PDF and embedding your image inside of it which may be subject to compression.

Also:

When using jpeg as input, add the "-quality 100" to your Imagemagick call to retain the highest quality possible.

Use a higher value for the "-density" parameter (I would recommend at least 150) to generate a higher resolution PDF.